# What is use of hash32() in String class?

Tags: java, string

Googling didn't help me out so I came here. What is the use of `int hash32()` method in String? As the name suggest it looks like for some hashing but how and where exactly it is used?

Comment: The standard [java.lang.String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) has no such function, at least no public one.

Comment: What version of Java are you on? If memory serves, `hash32()` was only in some versions of Java...

Comment: @user3580294:1.7.0(Seven).

Comment: [This](http://java-performance.info/changes-to-string-java-1-7-0_06/) might help.

Comment: No trace of it in the standard 1.7 either. Where did you find this method ? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: @JamesPoulson http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/lang/String.java#String.hash32%28%29 Also I'm not sure if it was really useful, as it has been removed in Java 8.

Comment: @JamesPoulson: I use `javap java.lang.String` command.

Comment: That's openjdk. You should not consider it as equivalent to Oracle Java as some aspects differ significantly. I once had to install standard Java on Ubuntu because it wouldn't run some software.

Comment: @JamesPoulson:I didn't get it. In what aspects ?

Comment: No. The method appeared in Java 7u6 and disappeared in Java 8. It also never was a part of the public API, it was an "internal" helper method.

Comment: @Slanec:Yes I am using java 7.

Comment: @P.K普 Well, I may be mistaken. However, I know for certain that OpenJDK differs enough to not be able to run Openmeetings. If memory serves correctly, something to do with a class being changed to an interface.

Comment: @JamesPoulson: Ok! got it..

Comment: @JamesPoulson:BTW how did you know I am using OpenJDK. I think it's not OpenJDK.

Comment: @Zouzou linked to it above. Sorry for confusing you two :p .

Comment: @JamesPoulson:That's fine. It's clear now. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is right [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/collections/changes7.html). Here are some choice snippets:

> Java SE 7u6 introduces an improved, alternative hash function...
>
> The alternative hash function improves the performance of these map implementations when a large number of key hash collisions are encountered.
>
> The alternative hash function is only applied to keys of type String.

As stated by @Slanec, Java 8 made some changes to `HashMap` that reduced the performance drop for heavy collisions to O(lg n) instead of O(n) for `Comparable` keys, so there was no longer a need for alternative `String` hashing.

Comment: Not strange. They removed it after they made `HashMap` more clever. Now it is able to chain entries with duplicate hashes into a red-black tree instead of a simple linked list. This solves the performance problem and therefore there's no need for `hash32()` anymore.

Comment: @Slanec Oh, that's interesting. I was aware that Java 8's `HashMaps` used trees where possible when there were a lot of collisions, but I was not aware that this was the reason alternative hashing was removed. Learn something new every day...